# Download pdf file from curl while url is redirecting

Tags: php, pdf, session, curl, download

I created one script in PHP. It logins on one website and then go to the list of the invoices on that website and I wanna make the script to download them. THe link of one invoice looks like this:

```
$newest_invoice_url= 
    https://secure3.billerweb.com/alw/inetSrv?client=701122300&type=ApplicationMenu&authTkn=r7mdbUaDHRqEWm4sbY1q40uvMhNQFjwDVOzhEZaAyFrGMyD0pTgCde/QHTSUf0YrJJw5PThCcAV8O7a2ipV5IZmi7jNGArIZ1ddy-WEJcuNAbMp0VRMnNO9VFCA7s78vwzB9VqCn/Qm5zfyzXH2YoNaqMATofgc3v-SSLYzzV3LGGVlvAF6TPS4JgPbcdxotOwJaGhPsM0qfoBiE74zECNA3o-x9-Amqa-/3Q1cRFUa3LtV77l/mDG1pQP1KbISD27TfSPvG1IgyzOz1BP6n0Ah4WksP95yAMhDUuaViKECBpC4n3n-SdyHyQpXz8UsPS8F3WWwj7aMwFvp2aaHRnP5j3uVl4gRGw1l3ee5BLmhkBZFdB57bcAP2Pinmk4krIuqvzjCZM780j9lMQ7E/lS-KqWQN/zrGF3JOg6CP3HYtna6Ne-XgseIxsf-Ecu7qKfZ-DRCSXtv1ulnn8PW1btvjgUeS-Aia8mo9T3CzUmVnbdkOG0JfrrT9mjHOUevqZb-48776CX9svPxujKVFjHELPX5E8bXzv2yIWyMoHfqpaVm1D2B2BP56GYwD5OQL0a5BNnsEjHBIpMMUCsGAbpXl0bABleBx&unitCode=ALW&keyTkn=W9EqaRvq0FQ_Ij9Nj1zRaPoc88pUKFGSOYlgLKY6qQxuLnHdhQ38Gq8CUviDeObpxvo46fbZ1XRjPTzMc0tTqCphM9Q79QjheglAX2Ay2Gzdo2r0KnRx9gBqoAyKSHk/93tuEmVAbszFdYfP0E-sJRCUWvnNUTDOe6TyEeblIzQ7wEDrNt4nmEI_&slchannel=ALWRSA&enc=web
```

This https://secure3.billerweb.com is not the site where I'm logged in, this a redirection link. SO I creatde this code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
$source = $newest_invoice_url;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt');
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array(
              'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36',
             // 'accept: application/json',
              'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
              'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9',
              'Content-Type: application/pdf',
              $auth_token,
              ));
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($data);
```

From this code I receive this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 15:44:09 GMT
Content-length: 0
Content-type: text/html
Set-cookie: _stkn-5VxD.GHe=419dZioHkOUhg6RZcU844Q__; Path=/alw/inetSrv; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
Cache-control: no-store,no-cache,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-security-policy: child-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; frame-ancestors 'self'; img-src * data: https://www.google-analytics.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google-analytics.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Location: https://secure3.billerweb.com/alw/inetSrv?sessionHandle=5VxD/GHel0zjLaUDhStfaVGhnhkpviikX-aSlAWWrj1U7BauY2w9NzAxMTIyMzAwJlJlcXVlc3RUeXBlPVNob3dQZGY_&client=701122300&type=CompatPresentmentService&action=ShowPdf&firstPage=true

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 15:44:09 GMT
Content-length: 1123
Content-type: text/html
Set-cookie: _stkn-5VxD.GHe=419dZioHkOUhg6RZcU844Q__; Path=/alw/inetSrv; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
Cache-control: no-store,no-cache,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-security-policy: child-src 'self'; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; frame-ancestors 'self'; img-src * data: https://www.google-analytics.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.google-analytics.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
X-content-type-options: nosniff
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

                                                                                                              
<head><title></title>
                     
<LINK REL="StyleSheet" HREF="styles/mainStyle.css">
</head>

<body>
<div style="float: left; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px">
    <div class="TitleFont">Operation failed</div>
    <div class="TitleFont">Reason</div>
    <div>
    <div class="custom-message-box">
                <div class="ErrorFont" ALIGN="left" >A server error has occurred.</div>
                <div class="ErrorFont" ALIGN="left" >Error reference id: YQL-99950</div>
                <div class="ErrorFont" ALIGN="left" >Time: Mon Jul 13 10:44:09 CDT 2020</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 600px">
        <p class="form-style-text">
        If contacting customer support, please quote the above error reference id. You may be able to press the browser Back button to return to the previous screen. Otherwise you may need to login again. We apologize for the inconvenience.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So my code is not working good, does anyone has ideas what should i do so i can downlaod this pdf file ssucefully?

Answer (score 0):

I adapted your code to test locally<sup>*</sup> and it worked as expected, so I don't believe the code is the problem. Your best bet is most likely going to be reaching out to someone associated with the website, but here are a couple things you can try first to troubleshoot:

- **Compare the HTTP logs from a successful exchange** in your browser (which you mentioned in your thread on reddit) to determine whether your script is missing a necessary cookie, header, etc. Refer to [this guide for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) or [this guide for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) if you're unfamiliar. You'll want to enable "Preserve Log" in Chrome or "Persist Logs" in Firefox since there's a redirect involved.
- **Verify that cookies are being stored** by opening `cookie.txt` and checking to see that the file is populated with what you see in the response.

<sup>*</sup> I tested your cURL options with a very straightforward [script that sets a cookie and redirects](https://gist.github.com/p810/5bba0bc5173671209298a34d0fb8c3ea), not the exact URL in your post.